# unable to fetch item from selected categories in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

i want to fetch the item of related subcategories but i am unable to fetch the items from that subcategories it is showing me the error

AttributeError: 'Subcategories' object has no attribute 'item'

so here is my code

my models

```
class Subcategories(models.Model):
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='our_categories')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Item(models.Model):

    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    subcategories = models.ForeignKey(Subcategories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    can_buy = models.ForeignKey(For, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    contain_size = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    first = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=False)
    second = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=True)
    third = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=True)
    fourth = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=True)
    fifth = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=True)
    item_vedio = models.FileField(upload_to='item_vedio', blank=True)
    offered_price = models.FloatField(blank=False,)
    actual_price = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    about = models.TextField(blank=False, default="about" )
    offer = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:subcategory_id>/products/',Product.as_view(),name='product' ),
]
```

my views.py

```
class Product(View):
    def get(self, request,):
        category_list = Categories.objects.all()
        return render (request, 'products.html', {'category_list': category_list })

    def get(self, request, subcategory_id):
        subcategory = get_object_or_404(Subcategories, pk=subcategory_id)
        products = subcategory.item.all()
        return render (request, 'products.html',{"subcategory_list" : products })
```

any idea what causing the issue and thank you for your time

Comment: i think you have to get the item because item has reference with subcategory like Item.objects.filter(subcategories=subcategory_id)

Comment: as you are getting the error AttributeError: 'Subcategories' object has no attribute 'item' model Subcategories has column or field named item but item model has Subcategories

Comment: Your `Item` model related name to `Subcategory` is `products`, not `item`. So use: `subcategory.products.all()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The related name is `products` for `subcategories` Foreign key in Item model.

```
subcategory.products.all()
```